# Mobile web app incompatible with iOS

Tags: mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk

I created a HTML5+Javascript mobile web app for Facebook App Center. It works correctly on Android phones, but when I run it on iPhone and iPad, it shows:

"APPNAME is incompatible with your device. Please visit the App Center to find apps for this device."

What could be wrong with my app?  I created another mobile web app in Facebook App Center, changed the URL to a simple test page, also changed the settings on the Permissions and  Advanced -> Migrations tabs, the app still failed to work on iOS.

The same problem happens when I try to run the app through Facebook App Center on my iPhone Safari web browser, and on my desktop Chrome browser using the iPhone user agent.  When I open my mobile website directly through my iPhone Safari web browser, it works OK.

Comment: Have you filed a bug report with Facebook? this should work unless the app accepts Facebook payments in the mobile web version